# Paginación pdf utilizando librería TCPDF de php

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

El motivo de mi consulta es el siguiente:

Me encuentro utilizando la librería TCPDF para generar un reporte en pdf, pero siempre me queda una página en blanco al final, quisiera saber como puedo removerla, adjunto mi código y una imagen, en este caso quisiera remover la pagina #3.

```
 <?php
    include __DIR__ .  '/../../config.php';
    if (!isset($_SESSION['sio_cedula'])) {
        header("Location: {$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']}");
    }

    # Requiero los controladores y modelos 
    require_once DIR_SIO . 'controllers/calidad_/servicio-cliente/sc-reporte-garantias.controlador.php';
    require_once DIR_SIO . 'models/calidad_/servicio-cliente/sc-reporte-garantias.modelo.php';




    #SE ESTABLECE EL HORARIO 
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
    # AUTOLOAD
    require_once DIR_SIO . 'vendor/autoload.php';


    class MYPDF extends TCPDF
    {

        /* ===================== 
            BUSCAR EL MES Y RETORNARLO EN TEXTO 
            ========================= */
        static public function mesNombre($mes)
        {

            $meses = [
                1   =>  "Enero",
                2   =>  "Febrero",
                3   =>  "Marzo",
                4   =>  "Abril",
                5   =>  "Mayo",
                6   =>  "Junio",
                7   =>  "Julio",
                8   => "Agosto",
                9   => "Septiembre",
                10  => "Octubre",
                11  => "Noviembre",
                12  => "Diciembre"
            ];

            foreach ($meses as $key => $value) {
                if ($key == $mes) {
                    return $value;
                }
            }
        }

        //Page header
        public function Header()
        {
            // print page header 
            if ($this->numpages <= 1) {
                $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                $solicitudGarantia = ControladorReporteGarantias::ctrDatosSolicitud($id);
                $fecha_despacho = $solicitudGarantia[0]['fecha_despacho'];

                if ($fecha_despacho == '' || $fecha_despacho == null) {
                    $fechaFinal = 'Sin fecha de despacho';
                } else {
                    $fecha = explode("-", $fecha_despacho);
                    $fechaFinal = 'Dosquebradas, ' . $fecha[2] . ' de ' . self::mesNombre($fecha[1]) . ' del ' . $fecha[0];
                }

                $image_file =  '../../views/img/plantilla/logo_coytex.png';
                $this->Image($image_file, 10, 10, 27, 17,  'PNG', '', 'T', false, 300, '', false, false, 0, false, false, false);
                // Title
                $border_style = array('all' => array('width' => 2, 'cap' => 'square', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'phase' => 0));
                $this->SetXY(12, 30);
                $this->SetDrawColor(127, 127, 255);
                $this->SetFillColor(56, 84, 153);
                $this->SetTextColor(255);
                $this->setFont('', '', 12);
                $this->setTextShadow(array('enabled' => true, 'depth_w' => 1, 'depth_h' => 1, 'color' => array(196, 196, 196), 'opacity' => 1, 'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));
                $this->Cell(0, 0, 'ANÁLISIS DEL PRODUCTO', 1, 1, 'C', $border_style);

                $this->SetTextColor(0);
                $this->setTextShadow(array('enabled' => false, 'depth_w' => 1, 'depth_h' => 1, 'color' => array(196, 196, 196), 'opacity' => 1, 'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));
                $this->SetXY(143, 40);
                $this->setFont('helvetica', '', 10);
                $this->Cell(0, 0,  $fechaFinal, 0, 0, 'C');

                // $this->SetTextColor(0);
                // $this->setTextShadow(array('enabled' => false, 'depth_w' => 1, 'depth_h' => 1, 'color' => array(196, 196, 196), 'opacity' => 1, 'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));
                // $this->SetXY(40, 44);
                // $this->setFont('', '', 9);
                // $this->Cell(0, 0, 'Código: PI-INDIGO-F001 Versión: 003', 0, 0, 'C');
            }
        }
        // Page footer
        public function Footer()
        {
            $empleado = ControladorReporteGarantias::ctrObtenerInfoEmpleado($_SESSION["sio_cedula"]);
            $infoEmpleado = "";
            $infoFecha = date("Y-m-d h:m:s A");
            if (count($empleado) > 0) {
                $infoEmpleado = "PDF generado desde el SIO por: {$empleado[0]['Nombre']}";
            }
            // Position at 15 mm from bottom
            $this->SetY(-10);
            // Set font
            $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
            // Page number
            $this->Cell(0, 10, $infoEmpleado . ' - ' . $infoFecha . ' Página ' . $this->getAliasNumPage() . '/' . $this->getAliasNbPages(), 0, false, 'C', 0, '', 0, false, 'T', 'M');
        }
    }
    class PdfOferta
    {

        static public function pdfPO()
        {
            $id_solicitud = $_REQUEST['id'];
            $solicitud = ControladorReporteGarantias::ctrDatosSolicitud($id_solicitud);


            // $muestra = $muestra[0];
            $pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, 'mm', PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

            // set document information
            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('COYTEX');
            $pdf->SetTitle('Solicitud: ' . $id_solicitud . '');
            $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
            $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, COYTEX, test, guide');
            // set default header data
            $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING);
            // set default monospaced font
            $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
            $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
            $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);


            // set auto page breaks
            $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
            // set some language-dependent strings (optional)
            if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php')) {
                require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/lang/eng.php');
                $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
            }
            // set default font subsetting mode
            $pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
            $pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 7, '', true);

            // Add a page
            // nThis method has several options, check the source code documentation for more informatio.
            $pdf->AddPage('P', 'A4');
            $pdf->Ln(38);

            # INFORMACION 
            $pdf->setTextShadow(array('enabled' => false, 'depth_w' => 1, 'depth_h' => 1, 'color' => array(196, 196, 196), 'opacity' => 1, 'blend_mode' => 'Normal'));
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '11');
            $pdf->Cell(0, 6, 'Señores: ', 0, 1, 'L');
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', '11');
            $pdf->Cell(0, 6, 'Comercializadora Arturo Calle S.A.S.', 0, 1, 'L');



            //1. ASUNTO 
            $pdf->Ln(8);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">ASUNTO</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $numeroSolicitud = $solicitud[0]['solicitud'];
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                    <p>Análisis de prenda Reclamo <b>No.  $numeroSolicitud.</b></p>
                    EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            #2. IDENTIFICACIO DEL PRODUCTO:
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">IDENTIFICACIÓN DEL PRODUCTO</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');



            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $producto = $solicitud[0]['desc_material'];
            $material = $solicitud[0]['material'];
            $ordenCompra = $solicitud[0]['orden_compra'];
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                    <p><b>Producto: </b> $producto</p>
                    <p><b>Material: </b>$material </p>
                    <p><b>Lote: </b>$ordenCompra</p>

                    EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            #3. MOTIVO DEL RECLAMO: 
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">MOTIVO DEL RECLAMO</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $observacion_calidad = $solicitud[0]['observacion_calidad'];
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                    <p>$observacion_calidad </p>

                    EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            #4. ANÁLISIS:: 
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">ANÁLISIS</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $analisis = $solicitud[0]['analisis'];
            if ($analisis == null) {
                $analisis = 'Sin análisis';
            }

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
            <p> $analisis </p>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            #5. MUESTRA FOTOGRAFICA:
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">MUESTRA FOTOGRAFICA</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $fotografia = $solicitud[0]['fotografia_prenda'];
            if ($fotografia == null) {

                $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td>Sin fotografías</td>
            </tr>
            EOD;
                $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
            } else {

                $fotografia_url = DIR_SIO . $fotografia;

                $html = <<<EOD
             <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
                 <tr>
                  <td><img src="$fotografia_url" style="width:230px;height:230px;"></td>
                 </tr>
            
             </table>
            EOD;
                $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
            }





            #6. CONCLUSION:
            $conclusion = $solicitud[0]['conclusion'];

            if ($conclusion == null) {
                $conclusion = 'Sin conclusión';
            }
            $pdf->Ln(10);
            $html = <<<EOD
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" style="text-align: center;">
            <tr>
            <td style="margin:500px;background-color:#d9d9d9;color:#000000;font-weight:bold;">CONCLUSIÓN</td>
            </tr>
            
            </table>
            EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(1);
            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                     <p> $conclusion</p>
     
                     EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(60);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                     <p>________________________________</p>
                     <p><b>Firma</b></p>
     
                     EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

            $pdf->Ln(2);

            $pdf->SetFont('helvetica', 'B', '10');
            $html = <<<EOD
                     <p>Alejandro Taborda Avellaneda</p>
                     <p>Coordinador de Análisis y Auditoria Textil</p>
                     <p>Laboratorio CO & TEX S.A.S.</p>
     
                     EOD;
            $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');



            $accionPDF = 'V';

            if ($pdf->GetY() >= 50) {
                $pdf->AddPage();
            }
            //Close and output PDF document
            $nombreArchivo = "sc-solicitud" . time() . ".pdf";
            if ($accionPDF == 'V') {
                $pdf->Output($nombreArchivo, 'I');
            }
        }
    }
    PdfOferta::pdfPO();
```

Muchas gracias, estoy atento
Actualmente utilizo la versión de php 8.1

No he podido pegar el código, pero adjunto imagen :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sin el codigo no se puede reproducir o ver que esta pasando, pero si te sugiero ver las delimitaciones y los saltos de linea

Comment: nonono, por favor borra la no respuesta :) Ya te ayudé, mira lo bonito que se ve el código

Comment: Soy nuevo en la página, no encuentro como eliminar la respuesta :(

Comment: No te preocupes. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: En la respuesta, justo debajo, hay varios enlaces para compartir, editar,... hay uno que permite Eliminar la respuesta :)